# Why would appendChild disregard zIndex?

Tags: javascript, css

I have very odd situation where I'm appending children (thumbnails) to a div and then I append a large blocking div to the parent div (all using appendChild) and for no reason that I can see the thumb divs wind up displaying above the blocker div (even though in the element inspector, they are in the right node hierarchy.

To be clear.

```
<div id="P">
   <div id="thumbs"></div> 

</div>

pseudo script:
fill thumbs with THUMB divs ;
P.appendChild(large blocker) ;
```

after this process the element inspector shows :

```
<div id="P">
   <div id="thumbs">
     <div thumb><div thumb>.... n number of times
   </div>
   <div blocker>
</div>
```

But the thumbs appear above the blocker.  I'm not setting zIndex on anything. the thumbs are being set with display:inline-block; Is there some obvious reason why they would not be behind the blocker div?

Comment: Do you realize that your sample HTML is full of errors?  Div tags aren't closed, you have random strings like `thumb` and `blocker` in places where you don't put a random string.  If this is your actual HTML, then all bets are off until you have legal HTML.

Comment: ha ha... yes, of course, it's just demonstrative of the structure of what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're manipulating objects with CSS to somehow overlap, objects are laid out in sequential order to not overlap.  Your thumbs come before the blocker div in the HTML so they should be laid out and assigned a position in the page before the blocker div which it sounds like is what you are seeing.  This is the expected behavior.

If you want the block div before the thumbs in the page, put it before the thumbs in your HTML (or use float or position: absolute).

If you want the blocker div on top of the thumbs, you will need to make the container `position: relative` and make the blocker `position: absolute` and give it an appropriate z-index to get it on top.

Here's an example that does position the blocker div over the thumbs: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/cxkmp/.  I've positioned it only partially over so you can see how it obscures the thumbs behind.

FYI: Your example HTML does not have properly closed div tags so it your real HTML is that way, that can also lead to massive confusion.

FYI: `z-index` applies to objects that are not `position:static` (e.g. most commonly `position: absolute`).  Objects that are `position:static` are displayed in child order without regard to `z-index`.

Comment: I'm an idiot... I wasn't setting an ID on the dynamically created div and it would appear that ID(less) divs don't behave correctly.  Adding an id solved everything.  I'm marking your answer as correct because it's a very nice answer :)

Comment: A div without an ID works perfectly fine.  I'm guessing you had a syntax error in your HTML.