# HTML-Element bring to front with "z-index" or "append"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML document has some HTML-Elements such as div, p, img, ...

Most of them are dynamically created ( if helpful css: "position:absolute;").

Every time after OnClick the element has to come to the front of other elements.

I mean:

```
element.parentNode.appendChild(element);
or
element.parent().append(element);
```

or

```
// E.g. with css as follows:
$('#ObjId').css('z-index', HighestIndx+1 );
```

I prefer the use of `appendChild`, due to the css style `z-index` won't be inserted into the element.
But I don't know whether the choice of `appendChild` vs `z-index` would be better.

My question: What is better to use z-index or append/appendChild ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would use z-index because I assume its faster and reliable in old browsers but anyway that's me.

Here is a useful article:
[Why would appendChild disregard zIndex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780349/why-would-appendchild-disregard-zindex)

The article implies some points but isn't entirely focused to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that appendChild() has anything to do with the z-index. It just add a new child to the calling parent to bottom as a last child. If you want to show your div in front of the other div then it is recommended that you should go with the **z-index** property.

Comment: That's right. But it can be also used in order to bring a object to front of others. But now I think too that the use of z-index will be better [Another link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233219/is-there-a-way-in-jquery-to-bring-a-div-to-front).